# Solve this equation apparently not as simple as it looks.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$\left(2m\cdot\frac{1}{2}\right)x=42$
what is X?

Need an answer to this equation and the working out as soon as possible please and thank you in advance, I've been told its not simple substitution or a simple linear equation. the answer x=42 is the incorrect answer.

Comment: What do you know about $m$? Is it just a constant? Then this is indeed a simple linear equation.

Comment: @NormalHuman this is all i have been given. If there is another way of looking at it so that it complicates both equation and answer feel free to do so.

Comment: Perhaps $m$ means *milli*?  If so, then $m=0.001$.

Answer (score 2):

HINT: we have $mx=42$ and can divide by $m$ and getting $$x=\frac{42}{m}$$